# How to change gridview paging numbers size?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a gridview and sqldatasource.
Paging is enabled in mygridview.

I would like to know if there's any way to change the size of the paging numbers. ( the numbers size below the gridview to be larger )

Thanks

Comment: Use CSS. http://forums.asp.net/t/1289820.aspx/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the **GridView** tag, you can include special tags for **setting the Pager styles**:

```
    <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First Page" LastPageText="Last Page" Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" />  
    <PagerStyle BackColor="Yellow" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Here is an [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=244) describing some of the options, and showing what they would look like. As you can see there, you can either set the font directly in the `PagerStyle` tag, or you can apply a CSS style like this:

```
<style type="text/css">   
          .cssPager span { background-color:#4f6b72; font-size:18px;}    
    </style>

<PagerStyle CssClass="cssPager" />
```